# Google Dataproc Agent reports failure when using initialization script

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to set up a cluster with an initialization script, but I get the following error: 
[BAD JSON: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Google"]
In the log folder the init script output log is absent.
This seems rather strange as it seemed to work past week, and the error message does not seem related to the init script, but rather to the input arguments for the cluster creation. I used the following command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create <clustername> --bucket <bucket> --zone <zone> --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 --master-boot-disk-size 10 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 --worker-boot-disk-size 10 --project <projectname> --initialization-actions <gcs-uri of script>
```

Comment: Does the init script live in a bucket the project cannot access perchance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently changing

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and removing all "sudo" occurrences did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This particular error occurs most often when the initialization script is in a Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket to which the project running the cluster does not have access.

I would recommend double-checking the project which is being used for the cluster has read access to the bucket.

Comment: This can not be the issue here as I use the following command: `gcloud beta dataproc clusters create <clustername> --bucket <bucketname> --initialization-actions gs://<bucketname>/testinit.sh ...` Even if the script contains a simple echo command it still fails.

Comment: No matter how simple the script, if the permissions do not work you'll see this error. :) Just to check, permissions are not an issue, correct?

Comment: The cluster has access to the bucket as it is the same bucket that is used for cluster creation. After the cluster is created (with given error) I can access the bucket from the cluster via ssh. I can copy files from the bucket to the cluster.

Comment: Can we ask you to send us some logs from the cluster? If that is OK with you, can you please try running `gcloud beta dataproc clusters diagnose my-cluster` where `my-cluster` is the name of your cluster? You will get a file location - send that to us `dataproc-feedback@google.com` - you will also need to give us (Google) permissions by running `gsutil -m acl ch -u google.com:R "<path-to-file-in-bucket>"`

Comment: @James, how do I check the bucket permissions?

Comment: @Maviles You can use the method(s) described here to do it. :) https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#retrieving-acls